# Jumping creates a distance between man and the floor Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The full code:

```py
import glob
import pygame
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (100, 40)

class Man(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # just taking random image to get height and width after trans scale to be able to crop later (see lines 23/36)
    idle_images_list = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\aviro\Desktop\מחשבים\python projects\platform game\animation\fighter\PNG\PNG Sequences\Firing"+'\*')
    random_image = pygame.image.load(idle_images_list[0])
    new_img_width = int(random_image.get_width()/2.5)
    new_img_height = int(random_image.get_height()/2.5)
    random_image_after_crop = random_image.subsurface((70, 35, new_img_width-125, new_img_height-45))
    # to be able to use needed images indexes

    # getting idle animations list
    right_idle_list = []
    left_idle_list = []
    for images in idle_images_list:
        img = pygame.image.load(images)
        wid = img.get_width()
        hei = img.get_height()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(wid/2.5), int(hei/2.5)))
        img = img.subsurface((70, 35, new_img_width-125, new_img_height-45))
        right_idle_list.append(img)
        left_idle_list.append(pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False))

    # getting movement animations list
    walk_animation_list = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\aviro\Desktop\מחשבים\python projects\platform game\animation\fighter\PNG\PNG Sequences\Run Firing"+'\*')
    walk_right_list = []
    walk_left_list = []
    for files in walk_animation_list:                          # setting the animation list
        img = pygame.image.load(files)
        wid = img.get_width()
        hei = img.get_height()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(wid/2.5), int(hei/2.5)))     # chaging scale
        img = img.subsurface((70, 35, new_img_width-125, new_img_height-45))
        walk_right_list.append(img)
        walk_left_list.append(pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)) # mirror list

    def __init__(self, x, y,):
        super(Man, self).__init__()
        self.walk_left_list = Man.walk_left_list
        self.walk_right_list = Man.walk_right_list
        self.width = Man.new_img_width
        self.height = Man.new_img_height
        self.hitbox = (x+55, y+35, self.width-125, self.height-45) # nothing special on those num, just Trial and error
        self.rect = Man.random_image_after_crop.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

def game_redraw():   # print things in end for main loop
    global right
    global left
    screen.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))
    if right:
        screen.blit(man.walk_right_list[frame_count//3], (man.rect.x, man.rect.y))
    elif left:
        screen.blit(man.walk_left_list[frame_count//3], (man.rect.x, man.rect.y))
    else:
        if last_action == "right":
            screen.blit(man.right_idle_list[frame_count//13], (man.rect.x, man.rect.y))
        if last_action == "left":
            screen.blit(man.left_idle_list[frame_count//13], (man.rect.x, man.rect.y))
        else:                                                                   # just for the first move
            screen.blit(man.right_idle_list[frame_count//13], (man.rect.x, man.rect.y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, man.rect, 4)
    pygame.display.flip()
    right = False
    left = False

def input_process(key):
    global right
    global left
    global last_action
    global man
    global frame_count
    global is_jump
    global neg
    global jump_count
    #
    if is_jump:
        if jump_count >= -10: # check if jumping
            if jump_count < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.rect.y -= (jump_count ** 2) * neg * 0.5
            jump_count -= 1
        else:
            neg = 1
            is_jump = False
    #
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.rect.right + speed < w:
        if left:
            frame_count = 0
        right = True
        left = False
        last_action = "right"
        man.rect.x += speed
    #
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.rect.left + speed > 0:
        if right:
            frame_count = 0
        right = False
        left = True
        last_action = "left"
        man.rect.x -= speed
    #
    if not is_jump:
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            jump_count = 10
            is_jump = True

w = 1728
h = 972
pygame.init()
RED = (255, 0, 0)
images_folder = r'C:\Users\aviro\Desktop\מחשבים\python projects\platform game\images'+'\\'
bg_image = images_folder+"background.png"  # setting background image
ground_height = h-143    # the high of the image ground
man = Man(200, ground_height)
man.rect.bottom = ground_height
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Refresh_Rate = 54
speed = 5
right = False
left = False
frame_count = 0
finish = False
last_action = ""
# jumping ver
is_jump = False
jump_count = 10
neg = 1
#
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
bg_image = pygame.image.load(bg_image).convert()    # can do convert only after setting surface.
# main loop
while not finish:
    if frame_count >= 51:
        frame_count = 0
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    input_process(key)
    game_redraw()
    frame_count += 1
    clock.tick(Refresh_Rate)
```

I'm trying to create a simple shooting-platform game, using pygame module. Everything works fine except the jumping. See in line 88. The player is jumping like an x^2 parabola. I added the *0.5 at the end of the line to make the player jump slower and lower, but when I do it this is what happened.

Before jumping:

[image]

After jumping:

[image]

Look in the second picture. There's a distance between the floor and the player. When I remove the *0.5 everything works fine. Why?

Comment: If when composing a question the editor provides feedback on requirements, please do not game the system to get around them. Those requirements are there to help you, not to make it more difficult to ask questions.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me?